# How to login the webapp using Azure Active active directory without using Microsft login page?

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

We have created an .net MVC 4.6.1 web application which uses the authentication by Azure active directory. When we run the app it redirects to Microsoft login page and after the successful login it enters to the webapp. My question is can we do the authentication using the Azure active directory by using API call that we will create the simple login page and in back end i will call the api with the user name and password. Based on the result i can decide whether the user is valid or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your own login page to get the user's username/password , and then using [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant][1] with Azure AD .However, use of the flow is discouraged for both security and functionality reasons. Please refer to [document][2] :

> > The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in
> > cases where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the
> > client, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged application.  The authorization server should take special care when
> > enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not
> > viable.
> > [1]: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/
> > [2]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3